# как подключится к Redis для кэша из Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, redis

```
сайт на локалке,
на локальный комп установил сервер redis как тут https://techvblogs.com/blog/install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04

все пункты кроме

Step 4: Install PHP Extension (Optional)
Next, if you need to use Redis with a PHP application, you need to install Redis PHP extension on your Ubuntu system. To install the Redis PHP extension, type:
```

так как я понимаю в Laravel 8 уже стоит в проекте по умолчанию Redis

App\config\database.php

```
    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?database=0'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL', 'tls://user:password@127.0.0.1:6380?database=1'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

поставил еще Step 4: Install PHP Extension (Optional)
и тогда заработало

Comment: Отвечу почему "заработало". Может познавательно будет. Да в Laravel встроенный драйвер для работы с кешированием через Redis. Но ниже для этого драйверу нужно PHP расширение php-redis которое умеет общаться с Redis непосредственно.